# Kafka streams - disable reading state from changelog

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've created an application using Kafka Streams, and doing some aggregations over my input topic.

Right now, when the application starts up it takes a few minutes for it to reproduce its state from kafka changelog (state dir is not persistent between start ups).

I would like to disable reading from changelog in startup, meaning it will start from scratch. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable change-logging via `Materialized#withLoggingDisabled()`.

All stateful operators (eg, `aggregate()`, `join()`) accept an optional `Materialized` parameter.

Comment: Is it possible to suppress also a suppress-changelog?

Comment: What is a "suppress-changelog"?

Comment: its a topic named XXX-KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE-0000000010-changelog. Can I disable logging for these too?

Comment: Ah. Not, that is not possible. But if you don't care about `suppress()` being "correct" (and correctness requires the changelog), you can just use `KTable` caches and omit `suppress()`